# how can I open an hdr in blender

Tags: import, image

I have tried to see where I can open the hdr files but could not find anywhere.

I want to open and view the 360 degrees hdr in blender. How does one accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying to open the image in the image editor or to see it spherically projected in the background of your scene?

Comment: @Duarte Is your version 2.78, that's what I'm using and I dont have the same view as your illustration. Thanks again.

Comment: I mean I don't have "surface" under "custom properties".

Comment: How do I know that @Duarte will look at this again? I have no way of contacting him! Nothing for that even on his profile.

Comment: Sorry @Duarte, I forgot the Cycles renderer! And thank you, I did it!

Answer (score 4):

Blender is not an image viewer application, you can't just use Blender to directly open image files from *File > Open*

You also can't just "view" images directly nor can you expect it to just open a spherical image as display it as a panorama viewer.

You can however use the builtin *UV Image Editor* to view regular images and use a workaround to view spherical 360 panoramas.

Starting a few versions ago Blender added support for world preview as viewport background. As a workaround you can use that as sort of a spherical image viewer. It will be obscured by the 3D View interface (grids, cursor and objects), but serves as a basic viewer.

With Cycles as your current render engine create a new *World* datablock from the *Properties Window*. Add a new *Environment* texture to its color input.

Pick the *Open* image button and browse your file system to the desired image file (JPG, PNG, or HDR formats).

Pick the image then in the *Properties Shelf* over the 3D View (<kbd>N</kbd> key) under *View* tab activate the *World Background* option if disabled.

You should now be able to use the 3D Viewport as a basic spherical 360 panorama viewer.

[image]

Comment: To disable grid, cursor, empties etc from showing enable *Only Render* option in the same Display scroll. It will disable any (including mesh) objects as well if they are set as non-renderable.